# std::tr1::array compile error

Tags: c++, arrays, tr1

```
C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
  ...char, 16>>, MAXPreBorder> _preCloselist)
```

my code is:

```
std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16> >
  dfs(Graphnode _root,
      std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16> goal,
      unsigned char _totalDepth,
      queue<Graphnode> _preload1,
      queue<Graphnode> _preload2,
      std::tr1::array<
        std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16>>, 
        MAXPreBorder> _preCloselist
     )
```

so the problem is this:

```
std::tr1::array<
  std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16>>, 
  MAXPreBorder> _preCloselist
```

Any idea it is wrong?

many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that your compiler doesn't like the `>>` in

```
std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16>>
```

This is only guaranteed to work in C++11. Try

```
std::tr1::unordered_set<std::tr1::array<unsigned char, 16> >
```

Comment: Many thanks!!! I could never figure out this myself...Thanks! I'm using mpicc it's solved by your suggestion!